# Problem with package dependencies

Tags: pi-3b+, raspbian-buster

So, I wanted to restore default settings for Raspberry Pi OS. I couldn't connect to the Internet because I changed some stupid keyboard setting on accident. So I jumped on Ubuntu MATE (with my other microSD card) and grabbed the .deb packages for dconf:

- dconf-cli_0.36.0-1_armhf.deb
- dconf-editor_3.36.0-1_armhf.deb
- dconf-gsettings-backend_0.36.0-1_armhf.deb
- dconf-service_0.36.0-1_armhf.deb
- dconf-tools_0.26.0-2ubuntu3_all.deb

(Sorry, had to type all the names by hand since I couldn't copy the name)
I installed all of them and now I have a stupid dependency issue with dconf-gsettings-backend_0.36.0-1_armhf.deb:

```
root@retropie:/var/cache/apt/archives# sudo apt reinstall dconf-gsettings-backend
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dconf-gsettings-backend : Depends: dconf-service (< 0.30.1-2.1~) but 0.36.0-1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libdconf1 (= 0.30.1-2) but 0.36.0-1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How can I downgrade dconf-gsettings-backend? I tried to use `apt --fix-broken install` and it wants to remove all the MATE desktop environment packages.

I tried to use `sudo apt reinstall dconf-gsettings-backend` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to restore default settings for Raspberry Pi OS, just flash its image to the SD Card.